# The kvm virtual machine not found bridge network in fedora 32

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I am configure a bridge network in my Fedora 32 machine,this is my ifconfig output:

```
[root@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv network-scripts]# ifconfig
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.31.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.31.255
        inet6 fe80::4b2:78ff:fe35:2c73  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 06:b2:78:35:2c:73  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 104  bytes 13776 (13.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 412  bytes 76686 (74.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

bridge0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.31.178  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.31.255
        inet6 fe80::b18b:62f0:b07f:1be6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 06:0c:7d:51:ea:71  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 31618  bytes 2354837 (2.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 13625  bytes 100610583 (95.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.31.72  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.31.255
        inet6 fe80::7903:4d64:5ea0:3339  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 2c:f0:5d:2c:6e:d5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 61756  bytes 26903282 (25.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 87934  bytes 108103869 (103.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xa1200000-a1220000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 5913  bytes 1277029 (1.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5913  bytes 1277029 (1.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:39:c6:9f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe36:a8ef  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:54:00:36:a8:ef  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 28  bytes 3449 (3.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 103  bytes 16899 (16.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

this is my network connections configure:

[image]

but when I configure kvm virtual machine network bridge in kvm virtual manager, I could not found the bridge network br0.what should I do to make br0 avaliable for kvm virtual machine?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bridge interfaces do not appear in this list. You must choose "Specify shared device name" and then type the name of the bridge interface you wish to use in the text box that appears.